# Automating a script to run after every git commit on team repo?

Tags: git, github

I have done a lot of reading about this but to no avail. I have a team repo on GitHub which creates a Git Page build with jekyll. Whenever anybody changes/commits a file, I would like to update other files in this repo. Is there a way to automate a script to run whenever anybody in the team commits anything? I have tried two methods:

**1. Pre-commit Hooks**

Basically, I have managed to set this up locally using a pre-commit hook in the .git directory, however I can only configure this on my local repo, not the remote group one.

**2. Jekyll Deploy Plugin**

I have also looked into the jekyll plugins, but as far as I can tell these also only work locally due to the `--safe` flag which jekyll uses to build.

Does anyone know of a workaround?

Comment: Thinking out loud here, but maybe you could have a post-commit hook that notifies a server and has that system perform the work (it can do a check out, run your script, and commit/push).  If these files need to change in sync though, a better option is probably to write a per-receive hook and just reject the commit if the other files aren't updated.

Comment: This would involve Github Enterprise I guess. I am trying to avoid this as I don't have an account so currently looking if I can achieve the same results from within javascript...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am now running a script to check for changes everyday using [launchd](http://www.launchd.info) which does the job, although I would have preferred some kind of hook.

The launchd script in turn runs a bash script:

```
date >> output.txt
cd /Path/to/Git/repo

git pull
python AnalysisToRun.py
git add .
git commit -m "updated after changes"
git push
```

If anyone comes up with a hookier, Gitier answer I am happy to change